# Is there a well-designed, maintained decision tree learning library for Java?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, data-mining

I need a decision tree learning library for Java.  I've looked at both [jaDTi](http://www.run.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/~francois/software/jaDTi/), and [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/), but neither is up to contemporary standards of library design.

For example, both still use non-generic Vector objects everywhere, and neither makes it easy to supply training data programmatically, they both expect data to be loaded from a file or a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at [JBoost](http://jboost.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org) has a decision tree implementation based on random forests. It is Hadoop-based however, not plain Java.

Comment: Ah, interesting - although the Hadoop dependency is probably a dealbreaker, as I don't need it

Answer (score 0):

Kind of old post but there is a very primitive Java based decision tree AI on [Github](http://xero976.github.io/taitree/)

Open Source Project: TaiTree